# Stop specific SqlDependency instance

Tags: c#, sqldependency

I'm using 5 SqlDependencies in my app.
Problem is:

```
static method SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString)
```

stops all my SqlDependencies. How can I stop only specific dependency?

Should I use "queue name"? .Stop() method also takes second parameter - an "sql server queue".
if so, how can I start each dependency in separate queue?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using 5 SqlDependencies

This does not make sense. Maybe you have created 5 query notification requests. Read [The Mysterious Notificaiton](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) to understand the terminology and how it works.

In any case, is a big no-no to call `Stop()` multiple times. Your entire app domain should call Start() exactly once (at app init) and Stop() exactly once (at shutdown).